# writing c# for loop to page

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn C#. A lot of the tutorials I've found write to the console, but I'd like to practice it in the context of a web app, and write my results to the page in some kind of control (literal, label, or something). I'm starting out with a simple FizzBuzz program, but for some reason it's only printing the last number in the loop (99). Any ideas how I can write out each iteration to the page? Thanks in advance

My code:

```
<asp:Literal ID="myLit" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

namespace practice
{
    public partial class fizzbuzz_csharp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                myLit.Text = i.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are writing the text directly to the control and not appending it.
At the end of the loop al previous values are overwritten and only the last one is shown

Change it to

```
MyLit.Text += i.ToString + "<BR />"
```

Answer (score 3):

You are always overwriting the `Text` property of the `Literal` control in the loop. That's why you only see the last. You could use a [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx) instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    myListBox.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

You could also append `<br />` to  wrap each line, although it's not good practise in web.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    myLit.Text += i.ToString() + "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting `myLit.Text` on each iteration of the loop, so its final value is `"100"`. You want to append to `myLit.Text` instead. For efficiency, this is probably best done by using something like a `System.Text.StringBuilder` and then assigning the final result to `myLit.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

Change inside of the loop to

```
myLit.Text += i.ToString() + "<br />";
```